# How to force order of folders in compiler search path?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

My 'Debug configuration - All platforms' search path setting is `..\PatchLibs`, search path inheritance is checked.

I want to temporarily add a folder to search in when a source file cannot be found in `..\PatchLibs`.

But if I add `d:\temp\folder` to the project search path setting, I get as search path

`D:\Temp\Folder;..\PatchLibs`
where I actually want
`..\PatchLibs;D:\Temp\Folder`

I cannot change this by editing the string, it just changes back.

Is there a way to accomplish this without modifying the 'Debug configuration - All platforms' search path? After all, I want it only this project.

Comment: So you want the `All Platforms` (root) to take precedence over the child, which is overriding or amending the root? That's the opposite of how the IDE works. Best not to fight it. Perhaps you can accomplish something similar using a `$(VARIABLE)` ?

Comment: you may dedicate an option set (file.OptSet) specifically to such extra options, then make you "Debug - All Platforms" hive inherit from it.

Comment: @Warren Mmm, I did not look at it that way. You have a point ;-)